# Need help to understand Rendering Problem Under Cycle

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have been following some online tut and there the node setup was working properly. But, in my pc the rendered image seems functional under Eevee while it's not looking that great in Cycles.
**Eevee** -
[image]

**Cycles** - Rendering Taking too much time than usual. So, sharing the viewport screenshot.
[image]

**My nodes setup** -
[image]

I would appreciate, If anybody can come up with an **explanation of the problem**, along with the **solution**.

Comment: Hey :). You're plugging stuff into the *Displacement* output. This is causing noticeably slower rendering in Cycles and a 'displacement'. Eevee doesn't support this feature, so nothing changes there.

Comment: Link the tutorial, perhaps you just missed a step :)

Comment: @ Jachym Michal. It is a paid course on Udemy

Comment: Well, then I can't really help more :). I explained why it happens, and since it's intended behavior, not a bug, there's no 'solution' per se :). You can of course simply *not use* displacement in your material.

Comment: Can you provide some reference material for learning about displacement textures, so, May be I could solve it myself.

Comment: Hey :). Try searching this site for posts about displacement and check the Blender manual. It's not a complicated topic :). Good luck.